# Fixed Nav bar with Grid Layout

Tags: css, layout, navbar, css-grid

I'm having trouble creating Navbars while implementing Grid LayOut.

https://codepen.io/Aeshtray/pen/BdqeZL

In mobile view, I want the Navbar to be horizontal (as coded), but fixed,
whereas after the first breakpoint, at 500px width, I want the Navbar to be Vertically Fixed on the left side.
I already tried setting the `position: fixed` but that only jumbles up my whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

Made some `css` tweakings, checkout this fiddle https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjgoKE?editors=1100

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdGBBo?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea how to implement the same to when the Navbar is left ( after 500px width) ?